# Java socket client doesn't detect server messages

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, bufferedreader, printwriter

I am attempting to run a Java server socket on a remote host which will regularly broadcast messages (determined by external processes) to all connected clients.

The server socket is defined as:

```
        ServerSocket serverSocket = (ServerSocket) ((ServerSocketFactory)ServerSocketFactory.getDefault()).createServerSocket(3050);

        while (true) {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            remoteService.addSocket(socket);
        }
```

Which will keep track of the socket connections in an array list. The method below will then be called whenever a broadcast needs to be sent:

```
public void broadcastMessage(String message){
    for (Socket socket : remoteService.getSockets()) {
        System.out.println("Sending message: " + message);
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        printWriter.write(message);
    }
}
```

On the client side, the setup is as below:

```
        Socket socket =  (Socket) ((SocketFactory) SocketFactory.getDefault()).createSocket(serverHost,portNum);

        BufferedReader socketBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        while (true) {
            String message = socketBufferedReader.readLine();
            if (message != null && message != "") {
                System.out.println("Message received: " + message);
            };
        }
```

The server is correctly printing the "Sending message" string as many times as there are clients connected, but none of the client processes print anything. Any idea how to get the clients to properly listen to the socket inputstream?

Comment: You are reading lines but you aren't writing lines. Wish I had a buck for every time I've written that here. Add a line terminator to the sent message,

Comment: @ControlAltDel The socket will not be closed until *it* is garbage-collected, which it won't be because there is still a reference in the collection. And closing a socket unblocks `readLine()` in the peer.

Comment: You're absolutely right - switching from write method to println to include the line terminator did the trick. All wokring now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PrintWrite.println() method will print the String it's given and terminate the line. Using the below on the server side worked:

```
public void broadcastMessage(String message){
    for (Socket socket : remoteService.getSockets()) {
        System.out.println("Sending message: " + message);
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        printWriter.println(message);
    }
}
```