# Error in sending bytes in java: buffered reader and input stream

Tags: java, java-io

I am trying to send a json string from a client to a server. The code seems to send the string correctly from the client, but the server won't receive the code and print out the results. What am I doing wrong?

```
        InputStream inp;
        PrintStream ps = null;

        while(true){
         try{
        ps = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream()); 
        inp = socket.getInputStream();
        brinp = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inp));
        System.out.println("hello"); //This works
         String input = brinp.readLine();
         System.out.println(input); //Nothing is printed here

         }
         catch(IOException e){
             System.out.println(e);
         }
        }
```

This is my server side code

```
//Socket s was initialized above
BufferedReader br;
DataOutputStream dos;
                try {
                    dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                    PatientStructure patient = new PatientStructure((int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1),
                            textFieldFirstName.getText(), textFieldLastName.getText(), new String[1]);
                    String sendString = gson.toJson(patient);
                    dos.writeBytes(sendString);
                    System.out.println("hello"); //This runs so my guess is that the above line has worked correctly

                    /**if (br.readLine().equals("ACCEPTED"))
                        dos.writeBytes(sendString + "/n");
                    else
                        System.out.println("Error");**/
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Both programs are connected to the same socket and problem seems to be in these lines. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: As in a thousand existing questions here, including [one only yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61512556/java-socket-client-doesnt-detect-server-messages), you are reading lines but you aren't sending lines. Add a line terminator to the sent message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java socket client doesn't detect server messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61512556/java-socket-client-doesnt-detect-server-messages)

Comment: If you are using a `Reader` at one side, why are you using a `DataOutputStream` at the other side? If you read with a `Reader`, you should write using a `Writer` (or the reading side should use a `DataInputStream`). You need to use the right pairs of classes and the right pairs of methods of sending/receiving data.